# Android GPS locations DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, ddms

I am doing an **android project** in finding *GPS location*.My app is working perfectly.I am using an emulator and i have to manually type the values in **DDMS>Location controls**.Is there a way to **store these dynamically entered manual values** into a **database**?

Answer (score 0):

Sure-  create a mock location provider.  It allows you to fake GPS data sent to the app. Have one read in the positions from a db.  Or use an existing app like FakeGPS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can you be elaborate.Iam not able to understand your solution.

Comment: Android has something called a mock location provider.  It allows you to override what the GPS system returns as location data, for testing purposes.  If you create one of these you could have it return the values you want.  That way you don't need to enter the fake GPS coordinates, your mock location app will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this right, I think what you want to do is create a GPX file. You can then "play" that into the DDMS window (there's a GPX tab next to the "Manual" tab you are typing into). Your GPX file will look something like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd ">
    <trk>
        <name>Test path</name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="27.622064" lon="-120.319935">
                <time>2013-10-10T10:53:14.679</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="27.622061" lon="-120.320083">
                <time>2013-10-10T10:53:26.666</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="27.622066" lon="-120.320238">
                <time>2013-10-10T10:53:38.699</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

That should give you the general idea!

Comment: Just one more thing on the GPX player... the buttons are very confusing. The "play" button plays the GPX file you've loaded, from the start. The "pause" one stops playing the GPX (and hitting "play" starts it from the start again). The forward and back buttons are toggles to play the file from the start forwards, or from the end backwards.